# How to write index to receive attributes for see and seealso entries?

Tags: xindy

I'm trying to get *pr.* suffix for index *see* and *seealso* entries with `texindy`.

```
\begin{problems}
\problem{Problems}
\index{Horner's rule}
\index{rule of Horner|see{Horner's rule}}
\index{Horner!rule|see{Horner's rule}}
\end{problems}
```

[image]

This is how I'm trying to achieve it.

- index.sty

  ```
  \newcommand{\inproblem}[1]{#1\indextagspace{}pr.}

  \def\@wrindex#1#2{%
   \indexmargin{\fbox{\parbox[t]{1in}{#1}}}%
   \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}{%
     \string\indexentry{#2%
     \ifindexasis
     \else
       \ifinproblem|inproblem%
       \else
         \ifinexercise|inexercise\fi
       \fi
     \fi
     }{\thepage}
   }%
   \endgroup % close group started by \index
   \@esphack
  }
  ```
- index.xdy (I also tried to play with `depth` attribute but w/o any success)

  ```
  (markup-locref :open "\inproblem{" :close "}" :attr "inproblem")
  ```

Intermediate result:

- book.idx

  ```
  \indexentry{Horner's rule|inproblem}{29} 
  \indexentry{rule of Horner|see{Horner's rule}|inproblem}{29} 
  \indexentry{Horner!rule|see{Horner's rule}|inproblem}{29}
  ```

I'm also getting these errors:

> ERROR: Cross-reference-target ("Horner's rule|inproblem") does not exist! [100%]
> ERROR: Cross-reference-target ("Horner's rule|inproblem") does not exist!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to add `pr` despite _see_. You can define a new command `\def\seepr#1{\see{#1}pr}` and use `foo|seepr{bar}` for index whenever you need both: _see_ and trailing `pr` at the very end.

Comment: @antshar Hmm... Seems, like I can replace the suffix `|inproblem` with `pr.` with this approach. But I'm still getting the same errors while running `texindy` because this command comes into play later on.